# Multiple Feature Sets

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, feature-extraction, text-classification

I am studying NLP and learning to use NLTK and scikit-learn for text classification. So I have implemented Unigram presence as a feature on the movie_review corpus of NLTK. Now I am trying to implement a research paper where they have used multiple features :

```
1. N-Gram Features : Unigram : Presence and Count, Bigram : Presence and Count
2. Stylistic Features : POS_Noun, POS_Adverb, POS_Adjective : Ratios No. of spelling errors : Real-valued feature Length of text : Real-valued feature
```

Since I have only implemented one feature function thus far, I am having problems now. I can implement feature functions for all of the above separately like :

def find_POS_Noun_feature(document) : for using POS_Noun as a feature to classify the text def find_Length_of_text_feature(document) : For using #characters as my feature etc. etc. Then I can train multiple classifiers separately.

But what I require is how to integrate all of these features into a single classifier?

Please help, I searched the internet but couldn't find proper explanations.

Comment: Well, what do your feature functions return? A 1-D array per data point? If so, you need to concatenate the the return values of all feature functions.

Comment: My feature functions return a dictionary.The labeled dataset that I feed into the nltk.classify.scikitlearn classifiers is a list of tuples where one part is a dicitonary and second is category. So, for unigram presence :  [({w1 : True, w2 : False.....},'pos'), ({w1 : False, w2 : True....},'neg').....]. Same for bigrams ans POS_Noun, Length_of_text etc.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your features in a single dictionary, regardless of origin or type. Just ensure that the feature names are distinct, so that you won't lose any keys.

If you already have separate functions that return *dictionaries* with different kinds of features, you can merge the results like this:

```
all_features = find_unigram_features(document)
all_features.update(find_bigram_features(document))
all_features.update(find_POS_Noun_feature(document))
etc.
```

If you have any functions that return an individual value (not a `dict`), you'd update the dictionary the usual way.

```
all_features["doc_length"] = find_Length_of_text_feature(document)
```

The feature function you train with will be the function that merges all these features and returns the combined dictionary.

Comment: Can such a all_features be fed into nltk classifier?

Comment: That's what it's for. Use it the same way you have been using one of the smaller dictionaries.